# Mac os x + libunwind

Tags: macos

I'm trying to use libunwind on a mac os x. However, the code is not getting any stack frames, while the same code running on a ubuntu box works perfectly fine.

Is there something i'm missing, that i have to do specifically for macs?

If there are better forums to ask such a mac related questions, i'm more than willing to accept suggestions.

Comment: You have any code to share? So we can try to reproduce the error.